# Der Unterschied zwischen "zu" und "zum" in Kombination mit einem Verb (Indikativ)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, nominalization

Ich weiß schon dass *zum* eine kürzere Form von *zu + dem* ist (Dativ). Aber in manchen Fällen kann man beide benützen wie zum Beispiel:

> Was gibt's heute zum Essen?

Oder:

> Was gibt's heute zu Essen?

Aber in anderen Fällen soll man nur *zum* verwenden wie in:

> Ich bin zum Töten bereit.
>
> Der hat mich zum Fressen gern.

(Und ja ich weiß, dass die oben genannten Beispiele etwas seltsam sind, aber das sind sogar Zitate aus Liedern.)
Meine Frage ist jetzt: Warum ist nur *zum* in diesen Fällen richtig? Und wie kann ich erkennen, ob ich *zu* oder *zum* verwenden muss?

Comment: `Was gibt es zu Essen?` Rehrücken. `Was gibt es zum Essen?` Einen Blauburgunder - nämlich zum Rehrücken. M.E. bedeuten nicht beide Fragen dasselbe, auch wenn beide gültig sind.

Comment: @ Em1, Oh entschuldigung, ich dachte dass Fällen "traps" heißen würde und Fälle "Cases". (http://www.dict.cc/?s=Fall).

Edit:
Ah nvm, ich habe mich geirrt. Es soll Fällen heißen weil es dativ ist :) und  "Fallen" heißt "traps", nicht "Fällen"

Comment: Ergänzend: 'Zum' wird benutzt, wenn das Verb zum Substantiv (noun) gemacht wurde. 'Zum' ist eine **Präposition**, genauer gesagt, eine Verschmelzung der Präposition 'zu' mit dem (bestimmten) Dativ-Artikel 'dem'. Präpositionen tragen eine inhaltliche Bedeutung … Dagegen ist das 'zu' in 'zu essen' keine Präposition, sondern eine Konjunktion, genauer gesagt, die **Infinitivkonjunktion**. Sie dient nur dazu, Verben in ihrer Grundform (Infinitive) mit dem Rest eines Satzes zu verbinden und trägt keine inhaltliche Bedeutung.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Frage

> Was gibt's heute zum Essen?
>
> Was gibt's heute zum (zu dem) Essen?

benutzt *Essen* als Substantivierung, deswegen benötigt es auch einen Artikel: *das Essen*.

Die zweite Frage ist aber eine Frage nach dem Verb, welches deshalb auch kleingeschrieben werden muss:

> Was gibt's heute zu essen? Was gibt's zu trinken?

Wenn es ein Verb ist, muss immer *zu* verwendet werden. Wenn es eine Substantivierung ist, nimmt man *zum* oder *zur* als Kurzform von *zu dem* oder *zu der*, weil ein Substantiv immer einen Artikel hat.

Wie man es herausfindet, ist vermutlich etwas knifflig und kommt natürlich darauf an, was man überhaupt sagen möchte. *jmnd. zum Fressen gern haben* ist z.B. eine feststehende, umgangssprachliche Redewendung, wo es eben so ist. Davon gibt es noch so einige. Allerdings kann man die meisten (einfachen) Substantivierungen auch durch ihr Ursprungsverb mit *zu* ausdrücken:

> Ich bin zum Laufen bereit. *oder* Ich bin bereit zu laufen.

Bei Substantiven, die ursprünglich mal Substantivierungen waren aber mittlerweile ein Eigenleben entwickelt haben, muss man etwas aufpassen. Dazu habe ich aber gerade kein Beispiel, aber bestimmt gibt es solche Fälle.